# Swagger JSON file download on NodeJS API

Tags: node.js, swagger-ui

I am new to swagger, I have written the logic for swagger UI docs, but I need to download that documented API docs as JSON file, can you please help me thanks.

```
const docs = require('./docs');
app.use('/api-docs',swaggerUI.serve,swaggerUI.setup(docs));
 


From ./docs.js


 {
  "openapi": "3.0.1",
  "info": {
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "title": "NODE SERVICE",
    "description": "This is a API docs",
    "contact": {
      "name": "Developer",
      "email": "developer@google.com",
      "url": "https://mkibui.me"
    },
    "license": {
      "name": "Apache 2.0",
      "url": "https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html"
    },
    "servers": [
      {
        "url": "http://localhost:9090/api",
        "description": "Local server"
      }
    ],
    "components": {},
    "security": [
      {
        "bearerAuth": []
      }
    ],
    "paths": {}
  }
}
```

I need to download JSON File like this

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you mean

Comment: u need to elaborate the question, the sufficient details is not provided to answer your question here

Comment: i have added the screenshot, i need to download the swagger.json file like above

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Follow the answer from [@Chintan Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17189039/chintan-shah), refer to e.g. the tutorial [here](https://github.com/ganeshmani/swagger-nodejs-tutorial) to learn how to annotate your API operations in the code.

Step 2: You can add the json API description that is generated when you start your node app to your Swagger-UI with an additional field `externalDocs` in the `options -> definition` for jsdoc. Looks like this:

```js
const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express');
const swaggerJSDoc = require('swagger-jsdoc');

const options = {
  definition: {
    openapi: '3.0.0',
    info: {
      title: 'API Name',
      version: '1.0.0',
      description: 'API Description',
    },
    externalDocs: {                // <<< this will add the link to your swagger page
      description: "swagger.json", // <<< link text
      url: "/swagger.json"         // <<< and the file added below in api.get(...)
    }, 
  },
  apis: ['**/*.js'], // Replace this with the path to your API routes
};

const swaggerSpec = swaggerJSDoc(options);

module.exports = (app) => {
  app.use('/api-docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerSpec));
  app.get('/swagger.json', (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(swaggerSpec);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A) Install the required packages

```
npm install swagger-jsdoc swagger-ui-express
```

B) Create a new file named swagger.js in the root directory of your Node application.

C) Add the following code to the swagger.js file.

```
const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express');
const swaggerJSDoc = require('swagger-jsdoc');

const options = {
  definition: {
    openapi: '3.0.0',
    info: {
      title: 'API Name',
      version: '1.0.0',
      description: 'API Description',
    },
  },
  apis: ['**/*.js'], // Replace this with the path to your API routes
};

const swaggerSpec = swaggerJSDoc(options);

module.exports = (app) => {
  app.use('/api-docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerSpec));
  app.get('/swagger.json', (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(swaggerSpec);
  });
};
```

To download the Swagger JSON file, go to http://localhost:your-port/swagger.json.

Comment: @shanthi-b did you got chance to check the answer?